# How to access local network devices on host network from VMware virtual machine in NAT mode

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vmware, nas

I have a network where a router connects an IP camera and a Windows 11 host machine. The host machine contains a VMware virtual machine Linux NAS server (shown below).

The NAS could only find IP cameras in its local network. How could I connect the camera to the virtual machine NAT network adapter network to let the virtual machine see it as a local device? (The VMWare network has to be set to NAT mode for other applications.)

[image]

Comment: Can you connect by IP address?  Do you have a double NAT in the blue block in your diagram?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another possible solution is to set all the devices on the 192.168.x.x ranges with a subnet mask of 255.255.0.0.  This should allow all the devices to see each using Layer 2 and their MAC addresses so it shouldn't require special routing or gateway changes.

Comment: I would add that in a large network this would be quite noisy, but if you are in a relatively small network environment without too many IP devices, this shouldn't generate too much broadcast noise. Upvote on accepted answer is always appreciated if it helped.

Answer (score 1):

You may add to the VM another network adapter that is defined as
bridged, so it connects to the `192.168.1.x` network.
The first adapter will stay as NAT, but the second one will be
Bridged, so it has access to the host network.

See the documentation at
[Add a Bridged Network](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/16.0/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-476EEC7C-4DBA-481B-A772-52CFC572E2A7.html).

Comment: I cant define the IP in the bridge connexion :(